# Which method is called when app which has been killed from background in iphone is opened again?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios10, appdelegate

After our app has been removed/Killed from the background either by iOS or by the user himself, which method is called when the same is opened again?

Well i believe, 'applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions' is called because since app has been killed, its is relaunched again. Is that so?

Comment: @Akaansha You are right, applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions will be called every time your app is launched.

Comment: Thanks. And what exactly is the estimated time in which iOS kills our app.? I read online they say its around 180 seconds approx.

Comment: If your app is not consuming memory or running any process in bakground, then it could stay for more time .All this depends on how many apps are running in background & when device gets memory crunch for running an app in foreground.For more details check https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH8-SW24

Comment: Thanks @Ellen :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right ! As it describe in the Apple Documentation:

[image: App launch]

You can also read the full version [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions.html)